# Problema al enviar datos de javascript a mysql

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, laravel-blade

estoy haciendo un sistema de quiz, estoy recibiendo datos desde mi base de datos y no tengo ningún problema con esto, estoy recibiendo los datos desde esta tabla

````
    {
        Schema::create('preguntas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id_preguntas');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('fk_categoria');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('fk_usuario');
            $table->string('pregunta');
            $table->string('respuesta_correcta');
            $table->string('respuesta_2');
            $table->string('respuesta_3');
            $table->string('respuesta_4');
            $table->string('retroalimentacion_positiva');
            $table->string('retroalimentacion_negativa');
            $table->integer('dificultad');
            $table->foreign('fk_categoria')->references('id_categoria_preguntas')->on('categoria_preguntas');
            $table->foreign('fk_usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('estado')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }```

Lo estoy recibiendo en mi javascript en el que cuento con una libreria de uso libre de JC Hamill en la cual construye el html de las preguntas que seria este
````

```
!function (a, b, c, d) { "use strict"; a.quiz = function (b, d) { var e = this; e.$el = a(b), e.$el.data("quiz", e), e.options = a.extend(a.quiz.defaultOptions, d); var f = e.options.questions, g = f.length, h = e.options.startScreen, i = e.options.startButton, j = e.options.homeButton, k = e.options.resultsScreen, l = e.options.gameOverScreen, m = 1, n = 0, o = !1; e.methods = { init: function () { e.methods.setup(), a(c).on("click", i, function (a) { a.preventDefault(), e.methods.start() }), a(c).on("click", j, function (a) { a.preventDefault(), e.methods.home() }), a(c).on("click", ".answers a", function (a) { a.preventDefault(), e.methods.answerQuestion(this) }), a(c).on("click", "#quiz-next-btn", function (a) { a.preventDefault(), e.methods.nextQuestion() }), a(c).on("click", "#quiz-finish-btn", function (a) { a.preventDefault(), e.methods.finish() }), a(c).on("click", "#quiz-restart-btn, #quiz-retry-btn", function (a) { a.preventDefault(), e.methods.restart() }) }, setup: function () { var b = ""; e.options.counter && (b += '<div id="quiz-counter"></div>'), b += '<div id="questions">', a.each(f, function (c, d) { b += '<div class="question-container">', b += '<p class="question">' + d.q + "</p>", b += '<ul class="answers">', a.each(d.options, function (a, c) { b += '<li><a href="#" data-index="' + a + '">' + c + "</a></li>" }), b += "</ul>", b += "</div>" }), b += "</div>", 0 === a(k).length && (b += '<div id="' + k.substr(1) + '">', b += '<p id="quiz-results"></p>', b += "</div>"), b += '<div id="quiz-controls">', b += '<p id="quiz-response"></p>', b += '<div id="quiz-buttons">', b += '<a href="#" id="quiz-next-btn">Siguiente</a>', b += '<a href="#" id="quiz-finish-btn">Finalizar</a>', b += '<a href="#" id="quiz-restart-btn">Reiniciar</a>', b += "</div>", b += "</div>", e.$el.append(b).addClass("quiz-container quiz-start-state"), a("#quiz-counter").hide(), a(".question-container").hide(), a(l).hide(), a(k).hide(), a("#quiz-controls").hide() }, start: function () { e.$el.removeClass("quiz-start-state").addClass("quiz-questions-state"), a(h).hide(), a("#quiz-controls").hide(), a("#quiz-finish-btn").hide(), a("#quiz-restart-btn").hide(), a("#questions").show(), a("#quiz-counter").show(), a(".question-container:first-child").show().addClass("active-question"), e.methods.updateCounter() }, answerQuestion: function (b) { if (!o) { o = !0; var c = a(b), d = "", g = c.data("index"), h = m - 1, i = f[h].correctIndex; if (g === i) c.addClass("correct"), d = f[h].correctResponse, n++; else if (c.addClass("incorrect"), d = f[h].incorrectResponse, !e.options.allowIncorrect) return void e.methods.gameOver(d); a("#quiz-response").html(d), a("#quiz-controls").fadeIn(), "function" == typeof e.options.answerCallback && e.options.answerCallback(m, g === i) } }, nextQuestion: function () { o = !1, a(".active-question").hide().removeClass("active-question").next(".question-container").show().addClass("active-question"), a("#quiz-controls").hide(), ++m === g && (a("#quiz-next-btn").hide(), a("#quiz-finish-btn").show()), e.methods.updateCounter(), "function" == typeof e.options.nextCallback && e.options.nextCallback() }, gameOver: function (b) { if (0 === a(l).length) { var c = ""; c += '<div id="' + l.substr(1) + '">', c += '<p id="quiz-gameover-response"></p>', c += '<p><a href="#" id="quiz-retry-btn">Retry</a></p>', c += "</div>", e.$el.append(c) } a("#quiz-gameover-response").html(b), a("#quiz-counter").hide(), a("#questions").hide(), a(l).show() }, finish: function () { e.$el.removeClass("quiz-questions-state").addClass("quiz-results-state"), a(".active-question").hide().removeClass("active-question"), a("#quiz-counter").hide(), a("#quiz-response").hide(), a("#quiz-finish-btn").hide(), a("#quiz-next-btn").hide(), a("#quiz-restart-btn").show(), a(k).show(), a("#quiz-results").html("¡Conseguiste " + n + " de " + g + " respuestas correctas!"), "function" == typeof e.options.finishCallback && e.options.finishCallback() }, restart: function () { e.methods.reset(), e.$el.addClass("quiz-questions-state"), a("#questions").show(), a("#quiz-counter").show(), a(".question-container:first-child").show().addClass("active-question"), e.methods.updateCounter() }, reset: function () { o = !1, m = 1, n = 0, a(".answers a").removeClass("correct incorrect"), e.$el.removeClass().addClass("quiz-container"), a("#quiz-restart-btn").hide(), a(l).hide(), a(k).hide(), a("#quiz-controls").hide(), a("#quiz-response").show(), a("#quiz-next-btn").show(), a("#quiz-counter").hide(), a(".active-question").hide().removeClass("active-question") }, home: function () { e.methods.reset(), e.$el.addClass("quiz-start-state"), a(h).show(), "function" == typeof e.options.homeCallback && e.options.homeCallback() }, updateCounter: function () { var b = e.options.counterFormat.replace("%current", m).replace("%total", g); a("#quiz-counter").html(b) } }, e.methods.init() }, a.quiz.defaultOptions = { allowIncorrect: !0, counter: !0, counterFormat: "%current/%total", startScreen: "#quiz-start-screen", startButton: "#quiz-start-btn", homeButton: "#quiz-home-btn", resultsScreen: "#quiz-results-screen", gameOverScreen: "#quiz-gameover-screen" }, a.fn.quiz = function (b) { return this.each(function () { new a.quiz(this, b) }) } }(jQuery, window, document);
```

Entonces aqui es donde se entregan las preguntas para que pueda ser construido que se las estoy entregando a través del metodo `public function obtener_preguntas (codigo de consulta sql)`
Y luego tengo donde estoy recibiendo todos los datos que seria en mi javascript y un trozo del codigo donde va el html, solo se llama a el javascript donde se construye el html para funcionar

```
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
    }

    function cargarPreguntas() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/obtener_preguntas', // Ruta que devuelve preguntas y respuestas desde el servidor
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                var preguntas = [];
                data.forEach(function (item) {
                    // Crear un arreglo con todas las opciones de respuesta
                    var opcionesRespuesta = [item.respuesta_correcta, item.respuesta_2, item.respuesta_3, item.respuesta_4];
                    // Mezclar las opciones de respuesta
                    shuffleArray(opcionesRespuesta);
                    // Encontrar el índice de la respuesta correcta en el arreglo mezclado
                    var correctIndex = opcionesRespuesta.indexOf(item.respuesta_correcta);

                    var pregunta = {
                        'q': item.pregunta, // Pregunta
                        'options': opcionesRespuesta, // Opciones mezcladas
                        'correctIndex': correctIndex, // Índice de la respuesta correcta
                        'correctResponse': item.retroalimentacion_positiva, // Retroalimentación positiva
                        'incorrectResponse': item.retroalimentacion_negativa // Retroalimentación negativa
                    };
                    preguntas.push(pregunta);
                });

                // Inicializa el plugin 'quiz' con las preguntas cargadas
                $('#quiz').quiz({
                    counterFormat: 'Pregunta %current de %total',
                    questions: preguntas
                    // Otras opciones del plugin 'quiz'...
                });
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Error al cargar las preguntas: ' + error);
            }
        });
    }

    // Llama a la función para cargar preguntas cuando la página se carga
    $(document).ready(function () {
      cargarPreguntas();
    });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <main>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="quiz">
                    <div id="quiz-header">
                        <h1>Quiz Variado</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id="quiz-start-screen">
                        <p><a href="#" id="quiz-start-btn" class="quiz-button">Comenzar</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

Mi problema es que he intentado varias formas de mandar las respuestas a mi base de datos pero no he podido y estoy muy frustrado ya que he intentado con ajax bastante pero no me a resultado y no logro entender porque intente dando la etiqueta csrf para no tener problemas tambien

    // Configura las cabeceras con el token CSRF
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    function cargarPreguntas() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/obtener_preguntas',
          method: 'GET',
          success: function (data) {
              var preguntas = [];
              data.forEach(function (item) {
                  var opcionesRespuesta = [item.respuesta_correcta, item.respuesta_2, item.respuesta_3, item.respuesta_4];
                  shuffleArray(opcionesRespuesta);
                  var correctIndex = opcionesRespuesta.indexOf(item.respuesta_correcta);

                  var pregunta = {
                      'q': item.pregunta,
                      'options': opcionesRespuesta,
                      'correctIndex': correctIndex,
                      'correctResponse': item.retroalimentacion_positiva,
                      'incorrectResponse': item.retroalimentacion_negativa
                  };
                  preguntas.push(pregunta);
              });

              // Inicializa el plugin 'quiz' con las preguntas cargadas
              $('#quiz').quiz({
                  counterFormat: 'Pregunta %current de %total',
                  questions: preguntas,
                  callback: function (index, item) {
                      // Cuando se responde a una pregunta, obtén la respuesta seleccionada por el usuario
                      var selectedOption = $('input[name="question' + index + '"]:checked').val();
                      
                      // Agrega console.log para depurar
                      console.log('Respuesta seleccionada:', selectedOption);
                      console.log('Respuesta correcta:', item.options[item.correctIndex]);

                      // Envia la respuesta seleccionada y la respuesta correcta al servidor
                      $.ajax({
                          url: '/registrar_respuesta',
                          method: 'POST',
                          data: {
                              selectedOption: selectedOption,
                              correctOption: item.options[item.correctIndex]
                          },
                          success: function (response) {
                              console.log(response);
                          },
                          error: function (error) {
                              console.error('Error al registrar la respuesta: ' + error);
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
          },
          error: function (error) {
              console.error('Error al cargar las preguntas: ' + error);
          }
      });
    }

    // Llama a la función para cargar preguntas cuando la página se carga
    $(document).ready(function () {
      cargarPreguntas();
    });
```

pero esto no funciona, espero que se entienda mi inquietud y de antemano muchas gracias, subo el proyecto por si no se entiende el codigo [APP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rXJ8_pkiiZkK0YlY5nYTxoZlW7EPzXHd/view?usp=sharing)

A modo de resumen el problema que tengo es que al momento de querer enviar datos a mysql desde javascript estoy teniendo problemas, incluso intentándolo con ajax en este punto no puedo encontrar que hacer

**ACTUALIZACION**

He logrado mandar datos a la base de datos pero no he encontrado como obtener el id de la pregunta y la respuesta seleccionada ya que todo se construye al momento de iniciar el formulario

```js
function manejarRespuesta(preguntaId, respuesta) {
  // Supongamos que tienes el ID de la pregunta y la respuesta seleccionada

  // Crear un objeto con los datos que deseas enviar al servidor
  var datos = {
      preguntaId: preguntaId,
      respuesta: respuesta
  };

  // Realizar una solicitud AJAX al servidor para guardar la respuesta
  $.ajax({
      url: '/registrar_respuesta', // Ruta en el servidor para guardar la respuesta
      method: 'get',
      data: datos,
      success: function (respuesta) {
          // Manejar la respuesta del servidor (puede ser un mensaje de confirmación, etc.)
      },
      error: function (error) {
          console.error('Error al guardar la respuesta: ' + error);
      }
  });
}
```